# How to make an interactive sidebar with jQuery and CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have asked questions like this and have not really got an answer that really helped me! I know it is probably very easy and i just can't figure it out!

I have been studying jQuery for a few days now and have the basics down but cant create the right function to make this effect happen! Please visit the website below!

There are a few things i would like to know about! The first thing is when you first go to the site everything slides into place (sidebar, footer, etc.) The main concern is the sidebar how when you hover over one of the icons a kind of tool-tip eases appears and eases to the right side.

The next part i would like to know is when you click one of the icons a whole another window pops out. I kind of have an idea of how these both happen but i cant put all the pieces together. Please help me out! I know it cannot be that difficult. Even if you know of any jQuery plugins that can help achieve these results, would be even better!

http://intothearctic.gp/en/

HTML

```
<div id="sidemenu">
     <div id="regionsContainer">
          <div id="regionsUnitedStates"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #sidemenu {
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 60px;
    height: 100vh;
    max-width: 60px;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-bottom: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    position: absolute;
}
#regionsContainer {
    width: 60px;
    height: 481px;
    min-height: 481px;
    min-width: 60px;
    max-width: 60px;
    max-height: 481px;
    background-color: #383D3F;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
}
#regionsUnitedStates {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image:url(../_images/_header/regionsUnitedStates.png);
}
#regionsUnitedStates:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
```

Comment: There is no website posted. Try something and post your code. Then you have a chance to get a good answer. Without any code or try outs we can't help you.

Comment: I posted now the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that using `position: absolute` like mentioned by fizzix before, and for each of your question with this html example

```
<div id="sidemenu">
    <div id="submenu" class="not-open">
        Sub
        <div id="submenu-inner">
            inner
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submenu-item1">
        item
    </div>
</div>
```

1 The first thing is when you first go to the site everything slides into place (sidebar, footer, etc.)

This can be achieved with jQuery on document ready, and using setTimeout if you want to further delay it, then add a class to the element, like this

CSS :

```
#sidemenu { 
    background: #000; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    transition: left ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
#sidemenu.show {
    left: 0;
}
```

jQuery :

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() { $("#sidemenu").addClass("show") }, 500);
});
```

2 The main concern is the sidebar how when you hover over one of the icons a kind of tool-tip eases appears and eases to the right side.

This can be achieved with only CSS on hover, what you need is put the floating element inside the element you want to hover, in this example `submenu-inner` inside `submenu`, then add some CSS

```
#submenu {
    background: #fff;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 150px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
#submenu.not-open:hover #submenu-inner {
    left: 50px;
    opacity: 1;
}
#submenu-inner {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
    top: 0;
    left: 250px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

firstly, the inner element is transparent and positioned more to the right using `left`, then on hover, set the position right beside the container, by setting the `left` CSS again to the width of the container

3 The next part i would like to know is when you click one of the icons a whole another window pops out

it's the same with number 1, except this one triggered by onClick event

here's the working example on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/23jHQ/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think any plugin is required.

You can use translate to keep the menu hidden.`transform:translate(90%)`

Please refer this example:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/hNSP8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

The entire site is using `absolute` positions. This means that they are positioned on the page with pixel co-ordinates. They then using jQuery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to move the `top` and `left` positions.

I have made a brief example of how to do this **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qqdCh/)**. You can edit this to your liking.

If you are interested in seeing what the site was built with, you can see a whole list **[HERE](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)**

Comment: I understand now so to do this effect when a page loads, do i just need to put it within a window.onload function and give it a specific duration or will that not work?